# Is it possible to edit existing Excel formulas using POI

Tags: java, excel-formula, apache-poi

I have one excel template placed in my application's configuration folder. Now while downloading that excel template, I am trying to edit it's data and existing formulas using POI api. I am able to edit data easily.

How can I edit existing formulas? The formula which I am trying to edit, is attached with more than 1000 cells, so instead editing every cell and updating formula, I am trying to update that formula itself.

I am using following code to get workbook object

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File("ExcelTemplate.xlsx")));
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(5);
for(int i = 2; i<174; i++) {
    Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("My Data");
}
FileOutputStream output_file =new FileOutputStream(new File("UpdatedExcelTemplate.xlsx"));
workbook.write(output_file);
output_file.close();
```

Problem which I am facing is as following:

I have one sheet (say sheetA) in which I am inserting values at run time. And I am referring that list of data in another sheet (say sheetB) as drop down for any cells. Now as per data range in sheetA, my formula should get change.

Comment: Well that code has nothing to do with what you're asking - where's the code you're using to actually edit the data?

Comment: Edited code b adding code snippet.

Comment: Whats wrong with `cell.getCellFormula()` and `cell.setCellFormula()` ?

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellFormula()

Comment: As I mentioned in question, there are more than 1000 cells which I need to update with this formula. Instead of that, I have one formula which is assigned to all these cells. So just updating single formula, all cells will refer updated formula which will improve my performance.

Comment: a formula isn't an object - you can't "update" it and it will magically apply to all cells. The formula is a property of a cell object so the only way to update the formula in the cells is to actually work with the cells directly.

Comment: It's a bit like saying you want to change the oil in your car without actually touching your car.

Comment: @Navnath: You should provide more informations about your formula and what exactly you want. First: There is no need to "update" a formula if nothing changes within the formula terms. Excel can and will recalculating all formulas if references, which are involved within the formula, have changed. Is this what you want?

Comment: Or is the need really to change the terms of the formula? Then this could be done using a `Name` which refers to a formula and then using this `Name` in the cells instead of the formula. Then you need only to update the `Refers To` of the `Name` to change the terms of the formula. But this is highly dependent of the kind of the formula. So more informations are needed for help.

Comment: @Axel, I have updated m question. And yes, I am checking with `Name`

Comment: @Navnath: So your question is how to change the `RefersToFormula` of a `Name`? If so, see: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NamedRanges. Sorry I'm still not sure what the problem exactly is.

Comment: @AxelRichter: I have done with `Name` object. I am testing it with all angles. Will post my code snippet to answer this question. Thanks that you pointed `Name` object.